# Javascript call function at the end of eventHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this global function that accepts a configuration object to display a parametric `$.dialog`.

this is the source

```
function close() {
    $(this).dialog('close').remove();
};
function modal(options) {
    var opt = {
        'modal': true,
        'width': 400,
        'close': close,
        'buttons': options.buttons || { Ok: close }
    };
    var dialog = $('<div>')
    .attr('id', 'dialog')
    .attr('title', options.title || 'Info')
    .append($('<p>').text(options.content));
    $('body').append(dialog);
    dialog.dialog(opt);
}
```

But I wanted to make even easier to call it by implementing a sort of small alert object with talking methods in order not to write ugly and log configuration objects, kinda like the `$.get()` and `$.post()` methods.

The reason for creating and destroyuing the `dialog` every time is that is much simplier to do that instead of rewrite an existing one.

My problem so far is that I have to remember to call the `close` function at the end of every eventHandler.

so my alert object looks like this

```
var alert = { //the name is work in progress, don't worry
    info: function(text, okHandler){
        modal({
            content: text,
            buttons: {
                Ok: okHandler //here I want to append automatically the close() function
            }
        });
    },
    error: ...
};
```

and I want to call it like this

```
alert.info('Success!', function(){
    doSomething();
    //then close without me having to remember to do so
});
```

Is what I want to achieve possible? I was looking into the `Function.prototype.call()` method to do so, but it's for other uses

Comment: It's very hard to understand the basic problem, can you explain your problem from a generic example without explicit project context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var alert = { //the name is work in progress, don't worry
    info: function(text, okHandler){
        modal({
            content: text,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                  okHandler.apply(this);
                  //here I want to append automatically the close() function
                  close.apply(this);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    error: ...
};
```

Comment: the scope of `$(this)` in `okHandler()` is the same?

Comment: see my change to the `close` line

Answer (score 0):

this question was bugging me because it seemed that i was still writing inelegant code. I think now I had the right answer, @Igor sent me to the right direction.

```
function handler(/*callback*/) {
    var callback = arguments[0];
    return function() {
        if (callback != null) callback.apply(this);
        close.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

function info(text, okHandler){
    modal({
        title: 'Info',
        content: text,
        buttons: {
            Ok: handler(okHandler),
            Close: close
        }
    });
}
```

the scope of the returned `function` from `handler()` will be the DOM element inside the `jQuery` eventHandler, `close()` will be called by default but won't be written many times.

At this point you could even call `handler()` instead of pass `close` (notice the parentheses) and achieve the same result.